# Kerning between V and / in Palatino and Euler

Tags: fonts, math-mode, siunitx, kerning

**Edit 1**

I made the test with real palatino font and Neo-Euler, with the same result
(As far as I can see)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[] {PalatinoLTStd-Roman.otf}
%\setmathrm [] {}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=upright]{euler.otf}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
Text  & MV/m \\
equation & $MV/m$\\
two mathrm & $\mathrm{MV}/\mathrm{m}$\\
one mathrm & $\mathrm{MV/m}$\\
siunitx & \si[per-mode = symbol]{\mega\volt\per\metre}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Original**

I am using palatino with euler as shown below.

I noticed a big space between `V` and `/`. I am not sure if it is because the slash is a binary operator or because the kerning is incorrect. 
I have this problem with the unit and it shown also with `siunitx`.
Do you also think it is too much space?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl} % rm
\linespread{1.05}        % Palatino needs more leading
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet} % ss
\usepackage{courier} % tt
\usepackage{eulervm} % a better implementation of the euler package (not in gwTeX)
\normalfont
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
Text  & MV/m \\
equation & $MV/m$\\
two mathrm & $\mathrm{MV}/\mathrm{m}$\\
one mathrm & $\mathrm{MV/m}$\\
siunitx & \si[per-mode = symbol]{\mega\volt\per\metre}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the Palatino font metric file has no kerning between V and /; the situation is the same with TeX Gyre Pagella. This might be a feature request for the TeX Gyre team (I don't think anything can be done for `ppl` now).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you modify your MWE to use `article` (to avoid artefacts of `standalone`) and add `\showoutput` to your document you will see that

```
Text  & MV/m \\
```

produces

```
........\T1/ppl/m/n/10 M
........\T1/ppl/m/n/10 V
........\T1/ppl/m/n/10 /
........\T1/ppl/m/n/10 m
```

So there is no font-specified kern between V and / in that font.

```
equation & $MV/m$\\
```

produces

```
........\U/zeur/m/n/10 M
........\U/zeur/m/n/10 V
........\kern0.83
........\kern-0.56
........\U/zeur/m/n/10 =
........\U/zeur/m/n/10 m
```

Net result is a small positive kern here, but note the `/` is from a different font.

looking in `uzeur.fd` we see this font is `zeurm10` and looking at the output of

```
tftopl zeurm10
```

we see

```
(CHARACTER C V
   (CHARWD R 0.646)
   (CHARHT R 0.691)
   (CHARIC R 0.083)
```

So `V` has a italic correction of .83pt which accounts for the first kern added.

the same file also has

```
 (LABEL C V)
   (KRN O 177 R 0.056)
   (KRN O 75 R -0.056)
```

which says there is a kern of -.56pt between (C)haracter `V` and (Oc)ctal 75 which is hex 61 which is `=` the slot with `/` in this encoding.

```
two mathrm & $\mathrm{MV}/\mathrm{m}$\\
```

produces

```
........\hbox(6.97992+0.15997)x16.67993
.........\OT1/ppl/m/n/10 M
.........\OT1/ppl/m/n/10 V
........\U/zeur/m/n/10 =
........\OT1/ppl/m/n/10 m
```

No kern, `/` again coming from the math font.

and

```
one mathrm & $\mathrm{MV/m}$\\
```

produces

```
........\hbox(7.48999+2.5)x30.52988
.........\OT1/ppl/m/n/10 M
.........\OT1/ppl/m/n/10 V
.........\U/zeur/m/n/10 =
.........\OT1/ppl/m/n/10 m
```

No kern again.

```
siunitx & \si[per-mode = symbol]{\mega\volt\per\metre}
```

produces

```
........\hbox(7.23492+1.20496)x31.56982
.........\T1/ppl/m/n/10 M
.........\T1/ppl/m/n/10 V
.........\T1/ppl/m/n/10 /
.........\T1/ppl/m/n/10 m
```

the same setting as for text with `/` coming from the same font as the letters with no kerning.

Comment: Strange how `0.083` translates to `0.83pt`...

Comment: @Werner the tfm lengths are multiples of the design size which is 10pt here.

Comment: i would expect no negative kerning in a math font; after all, the normal situation is for alphabetic elements in a math expression to be considered as multiplying one another, hence the usual positive italic correction (even sometimes in an upright font).

Comment: @barbarabeeton I _think_ I got the explanation of the -.56pt kern correct (feel free to downvote me if not:-) Or perhaps the comment was on the font, not my answer, in which case don't shoot the messenger:-)