# Define kerning in lualatex

Tags: fonts, luatex, kerning

I am trying to define a kerning between V and /. (see [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118547/kerning-between-v-and-in-palatino-and-euler))

My approach is the following, but I don't see any differences between using the feature file and not using it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mykern.fea}
languagesystem DFLT dflt;
languagesystem latn dflt;
feature kern {
pos \V  \SLASH -800;
} kern;

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[FeatureFile=mykern.fea]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
%\setmainfont[]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=upright]{euler.otf}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Text  & MV/m \\
equation & $MV/m$\\
two mathrm & $\mathrm{MV}/\mathrm{m}$\\
one mathrm & $\mathrm{MV/m}$\\
siunitx & \si[per-mode = symbol]{\mega\volt\per\metre}\\
%one mathrm & $\mathrm{MV/m}$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to use real glyph names from the font, I’m pretty sure `TeX Gyre Pagella` has no glyph named `SLASH`.

Comment: I thought I have to use the unicode names. I found that solidus and slash are synonyms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made it changing the `pos` line to
`pos V  \slash -100;`.